# iPhone Crash Log doesn't contain methods or line numbers

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

my app crashed, then I connected my iPhone to my Mac OS X, found the crash log in the "Device Log"-section of XCode.

What do I have to do to see methods or line numbers? I don't know where to look for the error with the information provided... Thanks a lot!

```
Incident Identifier: 3A2C8BCE-1393-4E50-9FEF-9CD5A5E39DD9
CrashReporter Key:   ddc16be00e41688d4e1443e0600a125a6b91dec8
Process:         my_app_info [1962]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A46A8FCB-7350-44B0-94DB-D783144FAB63/my_app_info.app    /my_app_info
Identifier:      my_app_info
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-06-16 23:21:30.242 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.3 (7E18)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3138cec0 0x31389000 + 16064
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3138eb84 0x31389000 + 23428
2   my_app_info                     0x0002a012 0x1000 + 167954
3   my_app_info                     0x00029de4 0x1000 + 167396
4   UIKit                           0x32614068 0x324a3000 + 1511528
5   UIKit                           0x326126e0 0x324a3000 + 1504992
6   UIKit                           0x325cbf7c 0x324a3000 + 1216380
7   UIKit                           0x325cbf38 0x324a3000 + 1216312
8   my_app_info                     0x00029d0e 0x1000 + 167182
9   UIKit                           0x325cbf18 0x324a3000 + 1216280
10  Foundation                      0x3372b5d2 0x336de000 + 316882
11  CoreFoundation                  0x323ef50a 0x3239e000 + 333066
12  Foundation                      0x337291ac 0x336de000 + 307628
13  Foundation                      0x3372b512 0x336de000 + 316690
14  UIKit                           0x325cbdb0 0x324a3000 + 1215920
15  UIKit                           0x325cbd48 0x324a3000 + 1215816
16  UIKit                           0x325cbc78 0x324a3000 + 1215608
17  CoreFoundation                  0x323b7eb0 0x3239e000 + 106160
18  CoreFoundation                  0x323adb4a 0x3239e000 + 64330
19  CoreFoundation                  0x323f5524 0x3239e000 + 357668
20  CoreFoundation                  0x323f4c18 0x3239e000 + 355352
21  GraphicsServices                0x335051c0 0x33501000 + 16832
22  UIKit                           0x324a6c28 0x324a3000 + 15400
23  UIKit                           0x324a5228 0x324a3000 + 8744
24  my_app_info                     0x00002332 0x1000 + 4914
25  my_app_info                     0x000022dc 0x1000 + 4828
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [symbolcate the crash log.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html) That will tell you where in your custom code the crash happened.

Comment: I don't get it... I used "build and archive" in XCode; now, I see the version in the Organizer.

When connecting my iPhone to the Mac, I see the crash logs in the according section; but again - without method names or lines... what am I missing?

Comment: You have to have the dylb file from the build that created the crash log. You can't use another build's file to read it.

Comment: TechZen is there any way to avoid crash logs that need symoblicating, i.e., include the dylib in the build itself (on iOS)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing this app then try debugging it in the simulator. I've found it produces more complete crash reports (dumped to the Apple console) than symbolicated device logs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to analyze crash report from apple:

1. Copy the release .app file which was pushed to the appstore, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report receive from APPLE into a FOLDER.
2. OPEN terminal application and go to the folder created above (using CD command)
3. atos -arch armv7  -o ''/'<.dSYM filename here>' . The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report.

Ex :  atos -arch armv7  -o 'AHLAN! HOT100.app'/'AHLAN! HOT100' 0x0003b508

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Thanks